# PHP How to get string before special character?

Tags: php, string, substr

I'm trying to get from this string:

> UPS EXPRESSS_SAVER - 1 día hab.

the portion of: `EXPRESSS_SAVER`

I tried the following code:
It starts from 4 index of the string  and finishes before special character "-"

```
$shippingMethod = "UPS EXPRESSS_SAVER - 1 día hab.";
$shippingServiceId = substr($shippingMethod, 4, strpos($shippingMethod,'-'));
```

This returned me: `EXPRESSS_SAVER - 1`

I also tried :

```
$shippingServiceId = substr($shippingMethod, 4, strpos($shippingMethod,' '));
```

But got: `EXP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code dot get EXPRESSS_SAVER

```
$shippingMethod = "UPS EXPRESSS_SAVER - 1 día hab.";

$shippingMethodArr = explode(" ",$shippingMethod);

$shipped = $shippingMethodArr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $shippingMethod = "UPS EXPRESSS_SAVER - 1 día hab.";
 $position = 4;
 $shippingServiceId = substr($shippingMethod, $position, strpos($shippingMethod,'-') - $position);
 echo $shippingServiceId;
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation, not just code. Add what have you changed and why.

Comment: Thanks, this worked too, it goes 4 spaces back from 1